# Custom Taxonomy Template won't show any menus

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, roots-sage

This is how I can start describing this, it's a very strange error that maybe something else but this is the first symptom I have.
I have a custom template`[taxonomy-location_types.php]` that shows, a custom post type `[locations]` by it's custom taxonomy`[location-types]`.

If you visit the home [page](https://stage.culturecollide.com/) you will see a menu *editorial, travel, etc.*
Now if you look here on this taxonomy [page](https://stage.culturecollide.com/location-type/landmark/)
The menu is gone, there are other queries that aren't firing but I'm focussing on this as a primary issue.

I have generated output from `nav-menu-template.php` like so:

```
    if ( $menu && !is_wp_error($menu) && !isset($menu_items) )
{
    write_log($menu);
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id, array( 'update_post_term_cache' => false ) );
    write_log($menu_items);
}
```

and I get this:

```
[31-Aug-2017 15:27:52 UTC] WP_Term Object
(
    [term_id] => 2
    [name] => Header Menu
    [slug] => header-menu
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 2
    [taxonomy] => nav_menu
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0
    [count] => 6
    [filter] => raw
)

[31-Aug-2017 15:27:52 UTC] Array
(
)

[31-Aug-2017 15:27:52 UTC] WP_Term Object
(
    [term_id] => 3
    [name] => Footer One
    [slug] => footer-one
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 3
    [taxonomy] => nav_menu
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0
    [count] => 5
    [filter] => raw
)

[31-Aug-2017 15:27:52 UTC] Array
(
)
```

So it sees the menu but for some reason return no items in either menu.
I have turned off all plugins and still get the same result, I have also eliminated all other queries on this page to see if there was conflict and this still this happens.

Any insight on this one would be great not sure where to look next for issues.

Comment: Just a quick note before attempting to solve the issue, shouldn't `! is_wp_error($menu)` on the very first line be `!is_wp_error($menu)` (without space)?

Comment: yes, went in and doubled checked that just a copy/paste error, code is correct. going to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Chalk another one up for RTFM, I had a `pre_get_posts` hook altering the query and I didn't ensure that the query it was altering was just the `$query->is_main_query()` because strangely enough this alteration was getting into the nav_menu query.

[query monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) is now my new best friend.